# how to: access typoscript variables from php outside of a controller context?

Tags: php, controller, typo3, typoscript, extbase

I want to access some typoscript variables from a global php script so I won't have a controller context to work with.  Normally I get these variable from inside a controller with code like so:

```
$this->settings['HallURL'];
```

How can I get the same thing while not in a controller context?  The variables are defined in my extension setup.txt like so:

```
plugin.tx_bpsmessagecentre {
    settings {
        # cat=plugin.tx_bpsmessagecentre//a; type=string; label=Default URL
        HallURL= Defualt URL
    }
}
```

Thanks

PS: I tried this, but it only works when the executing extension is bpscore, but I want to be able to access the same variable (set in the setup.settings of bpscore) from multiple extensions.

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup['plugin.']["tx_bpscore."]["settings."]["HallURL"];
```

PS:  Seems there is no great way to do this so this is what I'm going with so far -
in each extension I declare the common variables in the setup file like so :

```
   plugin.tx_bpsmessagecentre {
        settings {
            # cat=plugin.tx_bpsmessagecentre//a; type=string; label=Default URL
            HallURL= {$siteURL}
        }
    }
```

The common TS script included by typo3  defines  the variables like so :

```
siteURL = mydomain.com
```

then in global.php I define  function like so:

```
/**
 * getSettings
 * @param string $plugin  the name of the plugin whose settings to get
 * @return array
 */
function getSettings($plugin='tx_bpscore'){
    return $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup['plugin.'][$plugin."."]["settings."];
}
```

which I just call from anywhere in any extension like so:

```
$settings = getSettings('tx_something'); 
$url = $settings["HallURL"];
```

Of course if I'm in a  Controller context I can skip that and just call

```
$this->settings["HallURL"];
```

of course one problem with this is if I'm calling for the settings from the global.php file itself I have to do something hacky like this:

```
/** 
 * add a  part for each extension
 */
function getDebugb( ){
    if(isset($GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup['plugin.']["tx_bpscore."]["settings."]["DEBUGB"]))
    return $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup['plugin.']["tx_bpscore."]["settings."]["DEBUGB"];
    if(isset($GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup['plugin.']["tx_bpsmessagecentre."]["settings."]["DEBUGB"]))
    return $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup['plugin.']["tx_bpsmessagecentre."]["settings."]["DEBUGB"];
    if(isset($GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup['plugin.']["tx_bpscoupons."]["settings."]["DEBUGB"]))
    return $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup['plugin.']["tx_bpscoupons."]["settings."]["DEBUGB"];
    return "";
```

Comment: With a "global PHP script" you still mean one that is executed in TYPO3 context?

Comment: the global.php script is called for example at the top of a HippoController.php script but before the class declaration.

Comment: Is there a good reason why you would do that? Couldn't you use an AbstractController?

Comment: I want to get a bunch of variables defined on a TS file accessed by many pages and with plugins from different extensions.  So the HallURL  variable might be needed by code in many extensions.  I was hoping find a simple way to access those variables from a global function defined in one core extension and then just included in the others.

Comment: I would check to use an abstract controller that is inherited from by all your extensions. You should ask on the typo3v4mcv list to get help from the experts.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way would be to have a shared setting in all extensions, e.g.:

```
lib.tx_extension_share = {}
tx_extension.settings.share =< lib.tx_extension_share
```

You can also ask `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup['tx_extension.']['key']`.
But keep in mind that this is not clean from a conceptual point of view (OOP, SoC).

Comment: Interesting but I'm not sure I follow unless you are suggesting something like what I already have, please see my update and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ConfigurationManager for that.

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManager->getConfiguration
```

Experiment with the three CONFIGURATION_TYPEs to see what you can get. You can get anything from the typoscript setup.

For example, if you are in a Controller context

```
$settings = $configurationManager->getConfiguration(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_SETTINGS);
```

will get you the settings of the current extension.